# How to convert Moment.js moment to unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I see a lot in the Moment.js documentation about getting a Moment from a Unix timestamp. However, I am trying to convert a Moment to a Unix timestamp, and I am not sure how to do that. This is how my moment looks:

const myMomentObject = moment(str_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

And I need to convert it to a Unix timestamp.

Comment: Did you try doing `moment('str_time', "YYYY-MM-DD").unix()` ?

Comment: Just remember: the moment.js documentation also says to stop using it, because time passed it by =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unix timestamp can be obtaineded with or without the moment library.

```js
//Moment
const myMomentObject = moment('2021-10-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(myMomentObject.unix());


//Vanilla
const d = new Date('2021.10.16');
console.log(d.getTime() / 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Call `unix()` on `moment` object. [Reference](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/09-unix-timestamp/).

```js
moment('2020-12-12').unix()
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a Unix timestamp (seconds since the Unix Epoch) from a moment, use the following,

```js
console.log(moment('2021-10-16').unix());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Since your date format follows the [ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, i.e. YYYY-MM-DD you do not need to provide the input date format to the moment constructor.